# I use joomla 4.2.6 and pagebuilder .The addon form builder dont work properly

Tags: css, joomla, overriding, joomla-template

I am using joomla 4.2.6 and i am trying to change my contact form . I cant change the style .The addon has options for changing colour,border etc but it doesnt work .

The code from inspector(this code is inside my tamplate)

```
.uneditable-input {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 48px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2) !important;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

I  create a custom.css file to override and change things but it doesnt work for my form either. I will be pleased if i could change at least the border .Does anyone know why i cant override this code in my css file?

Comment: Did you add !important in your border setting?